# Covert an activity in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have the maniactivity which extends FragmentActivity(2 tabs with fragment).  I need to put the following listview acitivity in a fragment . Or please tell me how to how can I make a list fragment with these kind of resources.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ListView List;
    // Navigation drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private List<Category> albumsList;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_album);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();


        // Getting the albums from shared preferences
        albumsList = AppController.getInstance().getPrefManger().getCategories();


         // Insert "Recently Added" in navigation drawer first position
        Category recentAlbum = new Category(null,
                getString(R.string.nav_drawer_recently_added));

        albumsList.add(0, recentAlbum);

        // Loop through albums in add them to navigation drawer adapter
        for (Category a : albumsList) {
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(a.getId(), a.getTitle()));
        }

        // Setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        List.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * On menu item selected
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title

        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // Selected settings menu item
            // launch Settings activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running.

Fragment is owned by activity so you can't put a activity into a fragment. But you can do the similar thing in your fragment. For example :

```
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView List;
    // Navigation drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private List<Category> albumsList;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflate your layout here
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        // find your listview
        List = (ListView) findViewById(v, R.id.list_album);
        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // just like what you do in your activity...

        return v;
    }
}
```